# Environment.Exit producing a win32handle error randomly

Tags: c#, exit-code

I created a simple `toolstrip` item that exits the applications.

It saves data into a `datatable`, then gives back a `MessageBox` saying the save was done sucessfuly, and then exits.

It's hanging when I use  `Environment.Exit(1)`, while reading for some detail he would say it the thread could be waiting, sleeping, etc.

I tried using `Environment.Exit(0)` and somehow it worked, but i'm not really knowing why. 
I know it's related with a exit code, but being a "amateur" programmer I have no idea what it means.

Any hints? Possibly with reading sources directed to end-user programmers?

Comment: You'll have to document your question better.  You must enable unmanaged debugging and use Debug + Break All when it hangs.  Use the Debug + Windows + Threads window to select the thread if necessary, it is likely that you need to look at the finalizer thread.  The call stack you see is essential documentation for the problem.  If all this sounds like gobbledegook, it probably does, then just don't use Environment.Exit() at all.  A friendlier way to terminate your program is Application.Exit(), it cleans-up normally.

Comment: thanks, application.exit really did it

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `0` then it means **Success** but when you specify anything other than `0` then it simply means **Error**.

You can check [System Error Codes (0-499)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) also says:

> **Parameters**
>
> exitCodeType: System.Int32
>
> Exit code to be given to the operating system. **Use 0 (zero) to
>   indicate that the process completed successfully.**

Comment: you mean to tell me, i'm deliberately inducing a error? Also, why was the error random? Shouldn't it give the error every single time?

Comment: Please improve your post, right now it gives no hint whatsoever why the OP's program would hang.

Comment: @HansPassant of course it doesn't. That's what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: My comment was directed at Rahul, not you.  OP is you.